# Integral of Quasi-concave function is Quasi-concave

Tags: integration, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\mu$ be a finite measure on $X$.

If $f$ is concave on a Banach-Space $\mathbb{R}$, then
$
f(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y).
$
Taking integrals on both sides implies that the functional $f\mapsto\int_{x \in X}f(x) d\mu$ is concave on $X$, by linearity of integration.

However, it is not clear to me that the same is true for quasi-concave functions $f$...  That is, is $$
f\mapsto\int_{x \in X}f(x) d\mu
$$
quasi-concave on $X$ is $f$ is quasi-concave?

Comment: The inequalities involving $f$ denote convexity. Also the notion for $f\mapsto\int .. $ is odd as $f$ is not the variable but fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. This is quasi-convex. Set $X=\{1,2\}$ with counting measure. Then 
$$
x\in \mathbb R^2 \mapsto f(x_1) +f(x_2)
$$
is not quasiconvex: The points $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ are mapped to $1$, their midpoint to $\sqrt 2$. Hence the sub-level set to level $1$ is not convex.